# Which Ubuntu for Software Development

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

Please suggest me in this regard. I am having a Lenono PC and Dell Inspiron N5010 (both are 64 bit with 4GB of RAM, Intel I5 Processors). My requirement is:

**"A fully stable operating system (Ubuntu) on which I can carry out Qt
   application software development with readily available development
   tool chains (gnu) and preferably should support 64 bit application
   development".**

Which one: Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop/ Server? 32 bit/ 64 bit? Thanks in advance.

Regards

swamy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development I would just choose the desktop version. The server version is one that only comes with a command line interface by default. Since you have 4 GB of RAM, a 64 bit installation is adviced.

You can install any IDE or other tools you need from the Ubuntu Software Centre (GCC is installed by default), including QtCreator for developing Qt applications.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But unfortunately, my system will not be connected to Internet and its really tedious to install development tool chains on an offline Ubuntu machine. And I am in need of latest versions of gcc and Qt. Any how, thanks again for your advice.